# How to vertically-centered align images and characters in pmatrix?

Tags: matrices

How can I vertically-centered align the comma below with the images?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \includegraphics{image} & , & \includegraphics{image}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \]  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which vertical alignment do you want to achieve? Top aligned, bottom aligned, vertically centered, something entirely differetn...?

Comment: @leandriis: I'd like to have them vertically centered.

Comment: Try loading `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and use `\includegraphics[valign=c]{image}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the `valign=c` option from the `adjustbox` package, the images and the comma cen be vertically centered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \includegraphics[valign=c]{image} & , & \includegraphics[valign=c]{image}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \]  
\end{document}
```